# do something when terminate a python program

Tags: python, signals, try-except

I want make a python script do something such as publishing a message before terminating it.
I have tried `signal` and it works when I input `Ctrl+c` in cmd window.
However, it seems inoperative when I just directly close cmd window or kill the process from Windows task manager. So how can I reach my goal in the condition of above situation? 
Thanks for all suggestions!

Comment: I also have tried `atexit`, but it doesn't meet my need.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the atexit module:

http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html

Example:

```
import atexit

def exit_handler():
    print('My program just quit')

atexit.register(exit_handler)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a try according to your method, however, it's a pity that it doesn't work when I simply close the cmd window or click 'stop' in Pycharm where the python script is running. It works when I input `Ctrl+C` in cmd just like using `signal` method.